# Парсер на PHP

Tags: xmlparser, php

Нужно отпарсить большое количество xml-ек. Делаю через DOM. В результате получил ожидаемый результат, но лишь для первой xml. При этом в остальных xml количество полей (<Field>) отличается. Допустим в одной xml полей 10,в другой может быть 12-15.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/> 
<title>XML-разборщик</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('7035_983300001.xml');
$nObject=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Object')->item(0);
$nField=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(0);
$nField1=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(1);
$nField2=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(2);
$nField3=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(3);
$nField4=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(4);
$nField5=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(5);
$nField6=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item(6);

//Object
if ($nObject->hasAttributes()) {
    echo "Атрибуты тега 'Object':<br>";
    foreach ($nObject->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nObject->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Object
echo "<br><br>";
//Field
if ($nField->hasAttributes()) {
    echo "Атрибуты тега 'Records':<br>";
    foreach ($nField->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field
echo "<br><br>";
//Field1
if ($nField1->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField1->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField1->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField1->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field1
echo "<br><br>";
//Field2
if ($nField2->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField2->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField2->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField2->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field2
echo "<br><br>";
//Field3
if ($nField3->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField3->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField3->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField3->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field3
echo "<br><br>";
//Field4
if ($nField4->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField4->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField4->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField4->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field4
echo "<br><br>";
//Field5
if ($nField5->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField5->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField5->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField5->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field5
echo "<br><br>";
//Field6
if ($nField6->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField6->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}

$nName = $nField6->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField6->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field6
?>

</body>
</html>
```

ВОПРОС: Как сделать так, чтобы с помощью этого кода можно было бы отпарсить все xml-ки независимо от количества полей в них? Чтобы парсил все существующие поля... Данный код парсит только конкретно указанное количество полей.

Comment: отформатировать текст вопроса для начала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('7035_983300001.xml');
$nObject=$doc->getElementsByTagName('Object')->item(0);
//как-то так
while($doc->getElementsByTagName('Field')->item($i))
{

    $nName = $nField->getElementsByTagName('Name')->item($i);
echo "<b>".$nName->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nName->nodeValue."</em>";
echo "<br>"; 
$nValue = $nField->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item($i);
echo "<b>".$nValue->nodeName.":</b><em>".$nValue->nodeValue."</em>";
//end Field5
echo "<br><br>";
//Field6
if ($nField->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($nField->attributes as $attr) {
        echo "<b>".$attr->nodeName.":</b> ".$attr->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}
  $i++;
}
```

Нафига каждый пункт руками прописывать?

ps в коде возможны ошибки, так nxj тут только логика твоего скрипта, дальше сам домозгуй.